# Linux: assigning character ids from file1 to two columns of file2, f2_col1 and f2_col2 without changing the row order in file2

Tags: bash, join

I have two files (both with the same N=millions of rows)

f1.txt :

```
1       J100079
2       J100180
3       J100228
4       J100291
5       J100333
6       J100537
7       J100549
8       J100757
9       J100953
10      J101030
```

and f2.txt:

```
1       1       117656  0.494925
2       1       117656  0.0021814
2       2       117656  0.496289
3       1       117656  -0.00205095
3       2       117656  0.0024429
3       3       117656  0.495278
4       1       117656  -0.000898346
4       2       117656  -0.00520983
4       3       117656  -0.00694337
4       4       117656  0.495535
```

I wish to create a `f_final.txt` file that has assigned character ids from `f1.txt` to columns 1 and 2 of `f2.txt`, with no changes in the order of rows of `f2.txt`.

1. I started the process by creating an `f3.txt` as a join of `f1.txt` and `f2.txt`:

   ```
   join f1.txt f2.txt > f3.txt

   cat f3.txt

   1 J100079 1 117656 0.494925
   2 J100180 1 117656 0.0021814
   2 J100180 2 117656 0.496289
   3 J100228 1 117656 -0.00205095
   3 J100228 2 117656 0.0024429
   3 J100228 3 117656 0.495278
   4 J100291 1 117656 -0.000898346
   4 J100291 2 117656 -0.00520983
   4 J100291 3 117656 -0.00694337
   4 J100291 4 117656 0.495535
   ```
2. Separated from `f3.txt` two new files: `f4.txt` and `f5.txt` using cut (be aware that now the delimiter has become ' ' from join):

   ```
   cut -d$' ' -f 1,2 f3.txt > f4.txt
   cut -d$' ' -f 3,5 f3.txt > f5.txt

   cat f4.txt

   1 J100079
   2 J100180
   2 J100180
   3 J100228
   3 J100228
   3 J100228
   4 J100291
   4 J100291
   4 J100291
   4 J100291

   cat f5.txt

   1 0.494925
   1 0.0021814
   2 0.496289
   1 -0.00205095
   2 0.0024429
   3 0.495278
   1 -0.000898346
   2 -0.00520983
   3 -0.00694337
   4 0.495535
   ```
3. `f4.txt` is good (no more changes to it). For `f5.txt` I want to join it with `f1.txt` so I can assign to `f5.txt` numerical ids, the `f1.txt` character ids, but I do not want to change the order of the rows, so no sorting on `f5.txt`

   ```
   join f1.txt f5.txt > f6.txt

   join: f5.txt:7: is not sorted: 1 -0.000898346
   join: f1.txt:10: is not sorted: 10      J101030
   ```
4. step3 has an error. The last step would have been to column bind f4.txt and f6.txt with no changes in the order of rows.

   ```
   paste -d" " f4.txt f6.txt > f_final.txt
   ```

The final output could have been like this:

```
1   J100079 1   J100079 0.494925
2   J100180 1   J100079 0.0021814
2   J100180 2   J100180 0.496289
3   J100228 1   J100079 -0.00205095
3   J100228 2   J100180 0.0024429
3   J100228 3   J100228 0.495278
4   J100291 1   J100079 -0.000898346
4   J100291 2   J100180 -0.00520983
4   J100291 3   J100228 -0.00694337
4   J100291 4   J100291 0.495535
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: In your output sample, I'm not sure I understand the logic for the 4th column, for instance : `2   J100180 1   J100079 0.0021814` -> Why do you have `J100079` here ?

Comment: @Aserre, The 2nd and 4th columns and the 5th one are important, because they will be fed in another long program, which matches other large data internally by character ID, that does other mathematical estimations based on probabilities provided (5th column). Thanks for the html edits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution my way with join and sort:

```sh
join f1.txt f2.txt > f3.txt
cat f3.txt
join -1 1 -2 3 -o'1.1,1.2,2.1,2.2,2.5' <(sort -k1 f1.txt) <(sort -k3 f3.txt) > f7.txt
cat f7.txt
sort -k1 -k3 < f7.txt > f8.txt
cat f8.txt
```

If you have a shorter way that may save computing time to millions of rows joining post a solution. For sure I will not use cat, because I have tested it works with the toy example.

Answer (score 0):

This matches your example exactly:

```
join f1.txt f2.txt |
sort -k '3,3' |
join -o '2.1,2.2,2.3,1.2,2.5' -1 1 -2 3 f1.txt - |
sort -k 1,1 > final.txt
```

If you need the last `sort` or not is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dan and Robert,
The problem was braking down when numbers were becoming 1000ds and more.
So I had to change the solution to deal with numeric columns during sorting:
Following is the solution that works for millions of observations:

In STEP2
sort -k1,1n says: sort by column 1 and treat column 1 as numeric in sorting;
sort -k3,3n says: sort by column 3 and treat column 3 as numeric in sorting;

When using cut function (STEP4) will work correctly if -d (delimiter) is defined correctly as in the data. for example " " space.

In the STEP5 I introduce between columns TAB (\t) instead of blank space, because another program expects the columns of my output to be tab-delimited. So I used sed to substitute space with tab.

My remaining column 3, was necessary of a technical algorithm to be multiplied by 2. STEP6.

Finally the program clean the temporary files. If Dan sees these changes, especially the numerical treatment of variables, I would appreciate if he could reflect on his solution, which was quite good. Than you, Aldi

```
join -1 1 -2 1 <(sort -k1,1n f1.txt) <(sort -k1,1n f2.txt)  > fb_3.txt

'''cat fb_3.txt''';dash
echo STEP1

join -1 1 -2 3 -o'1.1,1.2,2.1,2.2,2.5' <(sort -k1,1n f1.txt) <(sort -k3,3n fb_3.txt) > f7.txt

'''cat f7.txt''';
echo STEP2

sort -k1,1n -k3,3n < f7.txt > f8.txt

'''cat f8.txt'''; 
echo STEP3

cut -d$' ' -f 2,4,5 ./f8.txt > ./f_fin.txt

'''cat f_fin.txt '''; 
echo STEP4

sed 's/ /\t/' ./f_fin.txt > f_fin0.txt

echo STEP5

cat f_fin0.txt | awk '{$3=$3*2; print}' > final_fin.txt

echo STEP6

rm fb_3.txt f7.txt f8.txt f_fin.txt f_fin0.txt

echo DONE
```

### Following is the solution as data: final_fin.txt

```
J100079 J100079 0.98985

J100079 J100180 0.0043628

J100079 J100228 -0.0041019

J100079 J100291 -0.00179669

J100180 J100180 0.992578

J100180 J100228 0.0048858

J100180 J100291 -0.0104197

J100228 J100228 0.990556

J100228 J100291 -0.0138867

J100291 J100291 0.99107
```